# Running an Android app on the server without an emulator

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, multiplatform

I have an Android app (Kotlin) that performs video transcoding work (via android.media.*).

I am looking to expose some of this behavior through a cloud-hosted web service, so that non-Android clients can also consume it. For example, the web service would receive a URL to a video that needs transcoding work, and would return the URL of the transcoded file.

Because the shared code is heavy on android.* dependencies, Kotlin Multiplatform does not appear to be an option for me.

An approach I am considering is:

1. Extract the shared code to an Android library
2. Create some kind of target that would allow invoking the shared code from CLI
3. Deploy a Docker container, with something like Anbox to emulate Android APIs

Does this approach seem sensible?
Are there better options or examples for accomplishing something similar?

Answer (score -1):

try [remote-android](https://github.com/remote-android), you can boot many Android Instances in server. It support `Android 8.1 / 9 / 10 / 11 /S` preview.